# Hibernate: data truncated at primary key column

Tags: sql, hibernate

I know that the question about "data truncated" in sql is so many in the stack overflow. But my question has a little different and I can't find the answer for that.

It's truncated in **primary key** when I'm doing update statement.

My function to update sql:

```
public void updateListData(String newId, String oldId) {
        StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder("UPDATE card_info c ");
        sql.append("SET c.xxx_id = :newId ");
        sql.append("WHERE c.xxx_id <> '' AND c.status = 1 AND c.is_private = 1 AND c.delete = 0 AND c.xxx_id = :oldId ");

        Query query = getEntityManager().createNativeQuery(sql.toString());
        query.setParameter("newId", newId);
        query.setParameter("oldId", oldId);

        query.executeUpdate();

    }
```

My log:

```
WARN : org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 1265, SQLState: 01000
ERROR: org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - data truncated for primary key column: <card_id>
```

I can't resolve this error.
Please help me.
thank you all!

Comment: why do you use this part "WHERE c.xxx_id <> '' AND" ?

Comment: I check null. So maybe I will use is not null for that :)

Comment: do you get this error for all update queries? according to description of the error code this comes when your newId is null or '' or you try to insert/update float column with no number

Comment: Only some queries is fail. But newId and oldId is always not null.

Comment: what is type of your card_id column? if newId is always not null it seems your newId out of range or type isn't same as column type.

Comment: Card_id type is int. card_id is a primary key, xxx_id is a normal column with type varchar(7). newId value is not out of range. I just update but error occurs at primary key. I don't know why.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I think you try to update cardId to not number value, or it is too big for your column type, e.g. `An Int can only accept values between -2147483648 to 2147483647.`
I suggest you to add some validation for the parameter newId before make update query.

Comment: card_id type int, xxx_id type varchar(7). I update with param: oldId = '4388421', newId = '4388420'. It's not to big :(

Comment: could you check card_id column for xxx_id=4388421? if it is '' or null it can be error reason